# Confused writing jquery deferred calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, deferred

I am new to using jQuery deferred as well as jQuery itself. What I am trying to do is make a call to an external function. If the the call is successful, I then want to call two more functions asynchronously. All of these call are to javascript library functions that are under our control. Each one is of the format:

Pseudocode:

```
    function <libraryFunction>(data) {
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url
            data: app.AddAntiForgeryToken({
                .
                .
                .
            }),
            dataType: 'json'
        }).done(function (result) {
            if (result.success === false) {
                deferred.reject({
                .
                .
                .
                });
            } else {
                deferred.resolve({
                .
                .
                .
                });
            }
        });
        return deferred.promise();
    }
```

The code I put together to achieve calling these functions is as follows:

Code:

```
var deferred = $.Deferred(),
    promise = deferred.promise();

promise
.then(lib.function1)
.fail(function (value) {
    .
    .
    .
})
.done(function (results) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred(),
    promise = deferred.promise();
    promise
    $.when(promise.then(lib.function2), promise.then(lib.function3))
    .done(function (r1, r2) {
        .
        .
        .
    })
    .fail(function (r1, r2) {
        .
        .
        .
    })
    deferred.resolve(
    {
        .
        .
        .
    })
```

This code works, but it doesn't feel like I am using jQuery deferred correctly, specifically at '$.when'. Is this correct, or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: When using $.ajax or the other ajax methods (post,get, etc) you already have a promise, so just return the chain, no need to create a new deferred

Comment: is correctly you need use console.log(return.data) to get the json you return or the error if avalible in php ...

Comment: Seems overly complicated, if the two functions don't rely on the previous result, you can do `$.ajax({options}).done(fn1, fn2)`, otherwise `$.ajax({options}).then(fn1).then(fn2)`

Comment: @PatrickEvans - Thanks. This makes more sense now. I was under the assumption that after the deferred was resolved (i.e. '.fail', '.done') the object would be gone and you would have to create a new deferred object.